# ntopng: Host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is a flooder [NNN new flows in the last 3 sec]

Tags: pfsense, flooding, ntop

I am exploring ntopng reports on my router and seeing, that one computer on my `LAN` is a flooder.

`ntopng` says `Host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is a flooder [NNN new flows in the last 3 sec]`

How to explore these flows in more detail to know if they are legal or not?

If I go to `flows` section of a given host, I am obtaining a list of flows which is much smaller than `NNN`. For example, I can have alert about 1500 flows, while I see only 100 flows in the list.

**UPDATE**

Screenshot

[image]